# Modify the image pixels using cvGet2D cvSet2D functions

Tags: c++, opencv

How can i use `cvGet2D` and `cvSet2D` to get this result:

[image]

Code:

```
std::string path = "C:\\image.jpg";
cv::Mat img = cv::imread (path);
CvScalar scal = cvGet2D(m, 0, 2);
cvSet2D(m, 0, 2, new_value);*/
cv::imshow( "Result window", img );
```

Comment: Or you just can draw a black rectangle... Also cvSet and cvGet are old C style functions. Never use them. Of you want to access pixels, use "at<>" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right rectangle corners:

```
Point tl(250, 250);
Point br(350, 280);
```

You can draw a black filled rectangle:

```
rectangle(img, Rect(tl, br), Scalar(0,0,0), CV_FILLED);
```

Result (note that my image has different size from yours, so results appear slightly different):

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Set top-left and bottom-right rectangle points
    Point tl(250, 250);
    Point br(350, 280);

    // Draw a filled rect
    rectangle(img, Rect(tl, br), Scalar(0,0,0), CV_FILLED);

    // Show result
    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

**Note**

`cvSetXD` and `cvGetXD` are old style C syntax. You should never mix obsolete C syntax and C++ syntax. If you want to access pixel values in a `Mat`, you should use the [at](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) function.